# Trouble passing eventcallback to component which inherits InputBase<TValue>

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I am developing a custom select component which is inherited from, InputBase as follows:

Index.razor:

```
<Select Id="InvestmentEntity"
    OnSelected="@OnInvestmentEntitySelect"
</Select>
```

Index.razor.cs

```
public void OnInvestmentEntitySelect(Select<int> sender)
{
    // .. do something later
}
```

Select.razor.cs

```
namespace Accounting.Web.Components.Forms
{
    public partial class Select<TValue> : InputBase<TValue>
    {
        [Parameter]
        public EventCallback<Select<TValue>> OnSelected { get; set; } = default!;


        protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out TValue result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string? validationErrorMessage)
        {            
            if (BindConverter.TryConvertTo<TValue>(value, null, out result))
            {
                validationErrorMessage = "";
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                validationErrorMessage = "Err : Select value";
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void OnSelect(SelectOption? option)
        {
            OnSelected.InvokeAsync(this);
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see I am attempting to pass a callback event via the component tag (OnSelected) which is invoked the Select.razor.cs file.  However the compiler is returning the following error in relation to this line:

```
OnSelected="@OnInvestmentEntitySelect"
```

Error:

Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'EventCallback'

If I try the following, I get a different error:

```
OnSelected="@(() => OnInvestmentEntitySelect)"
```

Errors:

```
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
'OnInvestmentEntitySelect' to non-delegate type 'Task'. Did you intend to invoke the method?
Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
```

How can I pass the method to the even callback parameter so that it is called when invoked by the component in the scenario above?  My objective is to pass the reference of the instance of the component which invoked the event back as a parameter to the callback method in the parent page

Comment: You almost had it. Try: `OnSelected="@(() => OnInvestmentEntitySelect())"`. You just need to call your method inside the lambda expression.

Comment: @Axekan this produces a different error: "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'sender' of 'Add.OnInvestmentEntitySelect(Select<int>)' "

Comment: How about ```OnSelected="(s) => OnInvestmentEntitySelect(s)"```? However depending on what you are doing after, you might want to use a ```@ref``` of your Select instance in Index.razor instead. Simpler than passing component references around. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#capture-references-to-components

Comment: Remove the quotes around the method `OnSelected=@OnInvestmentEntitySelect`

Comment: @MisterMagoo this didn't work unfortunately

Comment: @Axekan this also didn't work - I instead opted to pass a custom class in the callback to relay the information required.

Comment: [Polite] Curious as to why you are trying to pass `this` - a component `Select<TValue>` - in the Callback?  What are you doing with it in the parent?  Passing components around is not normally good practice.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis it was purely for convenience initially, to have access to all properties of the instance which invoked the callback.  I have since then reconsidered this approach and used a custom callback class instead.  I am still, however, left a little restless not having been able to pass the component as the parameter in case I need to do this someday,

Comment: Using a simple data class is the best approach for both up and down component communications.  You can normally use a record or a readonly struct.  Don't cascade a component to it's sub-components and likewise passing `this` in a callback.  Two principle reasons: 1. You don't control the lifecycle of a component, the Renderer does.  You could easily try and do things on a dispose instance.  2. There's a lot of exposed functionality that simply wasn't designed to be use in such a context.